# Interrupt SetOnTouchListener during moving event

Tags: java, android, interrupt, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I try to interrupt my setOnTouchListener which I declared for a ImageView.
The point is to stop the listener and make a kind of "reset" on it, and on my ImaeView Layout too, when the user finger is near to the top of the screen.

My steps are :
->Create OnTouchListener
->Store finger position
->If the finger is near to the top of the screen (100pixels), reset the layout of the ImageView as default in activity layout xml file, and interrupt the Listener.
->To reuse the OnTouchListener, the user has to put his finger up.

My code is like that :

```
private void readyDeck() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    backCard = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.leader_backCardImg);
    backCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    backCard.setAlpha(255);
    backCard.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {


            int eid = me.getAction();
            switch(eid){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) backCard.getLayoutParams();
                    int y = (int) me.getRawY();
                    mParams.topMargin = y-height+(backCard.getHeight()/(1+(1/2)));
                    backCard.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                    int limit = backCard.getHeight();

                    if(y > limit){
                        mParams.topMargin = limit;
                        backCard.setLayoutParams(mParams);
                    }

                    else if(y < 255){
                        backCard.setAlpha(y);
                        if(y < 100){

                            backCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            backCard.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            sendData();
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

The sendData() method has to reset the listener, but if I code just like this :

```
public void sendData(){
   readyDeck();
}
```

The position of the finger is always stored and used even if we did'nt put it out of the screen.

You can see it by add some operations in sendData() method, like remove one random item of an ArrayList, and here the logCat :

```
12-13 08:01:06.400: I/System.out(17171): s4 removed.New Size : 51
12-13 08:01:06.460: I/System.out(17171): h6 removed.New Size : 50
12-13 08:01:06.520: I/System.out(17171): h1 removed.New Size : 49
12-13 08:01:06.560: I/System.out(17171): c1 removed.New Size : 48
12-13 08:01:06.605: I/System.out(17171): hk removed.New Size : 47
12-13 08:01:06.630: I/System.out(17171): d9 removed.New Size : 46
12-13 08:01:06.655: I/System.out(17171): d2 removed.New Size : 45
12-13 08:01:06.695: I/System.out(17171): h2 removed.New Size : 44
12-13 08:01:06.730: I/System.out(17171): d8 removed.New Size : 43
12-13 08:01:06.760: I/System.out(17171): s10 removed.New Size : 42
12-13 08:01:06.800: I/System.out(17171): h7 removed.New Size : 41
12-13 08:01:06.830: I/System.out(17171): d6 removed.New Size : 40
12-13 08:01:06.850: I/System.out(17171): h9 removed.New Size : 39
12-13 08:01:06.900: I/System.out(17171): s6 removed.New Size : 38
12-13 08:01:07.250: I/System.out(17171): c4 removed.New Size : 37
12-13 08:01:07.275: I/System.out(17171): d3 removed.New Size : 36
12-13 08:01:07.300: I/System.out(17171): cv removed.New Size : 35
```

We can see the method doesn't stop the Listener, because just after decalre it null, the Listener is again loaded with boolen OnTouch().

Do you have a method to interrupt the listener ? And to more, to reset the layout of my ImageView ? Thank you !

Comment: your question is confusing.. can you re-phrase it.. step by step tell what you want and what is going wrong?

Comment: My steps are :
->Create OnTouchListener
->Store finger position
->If the finger is near to the top of the screen (100pixels), reset the layout of the ImageView as default in activity layout xml file, and interrupt the Listener.
->To reuse the OnTouchListener, the user has to put his finger up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just return false when you call sendData(), that should prevent further calls to your onTouch method for the current touch event.  From the [developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html):

onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action event.

Comment: I tried to return false after call sendData(), instead of break; but it's the same.

Comment: Wait am I misreading your code?  It appears that you've set up an infinite loop.  You call sendData() from the onTouchListener, which calls readyDeck(), which reattaches the onTouchListener.  So the next time a touch event happens, backCard will pick it up again.  And actually, try returning false at the bottom of your onTouch as well.